# Aggregation or composition

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am bit confused so if you can enlighten me please.

1. When I create an object through new operator in my class or using Singleton is it a composition?
2. When I call a factory method is it composition too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composition vs. Aggregation has to do with component object lifetime, not how the component objects are instantiated. If component objects are disposed of when the containing object is disposed of, it's Composition. If the component objects can live on, it's Aggregation.

Comment: To get this straight let's say that I have a class BookShop and BookShopStuff(and subclasses like Books, Newspapers...). Each object of BookShopStuff I store in BookShop array let's say. Is this composition then? Or BookShop aggregates BookShopStuff elements? I am confused.

Comment: Ok, books are good. Can books in a bookshop continue to exist without the bookshop? If yes then it's Aggregation, if not, it's Composition.

Comment: They can't exist because BookShop is the only place where all instances are kept. So it is a composition.

Comment: Ahh, be careful. That's an implementation detail. In the real world, books don't need a bookshop.

Comment: Does it mean it's not composition for given example? Do I get this right? So there must be the same dependency from either side. If I remove Book can BookShop exist - yes, if I remove BookShop can Book exist - no. Different so not a composition?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you want it to work, there is no One Right Answer. If for your purposes, it makes sense to have the books go away when the bookshop goes away, it's Composition. If the books should remain, it's Aggregation. If you were tracking books across a library system, you might use aggregation, so that when a library closes, you don't loose books. If you were writing a custom application for a bookstore, you might use composition; who cares about the books if the bookstore goes out of business?

Comment: So in that case only implementation matters when it comes to identifying object composition in the system. I hope I got that right now ;)

Comment: In the real world, yes. You need to understand what you plan to do and whether of not it meets your needs.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you very much for being very patient preceptor on the subject :) Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

The term "composition" has slightly different meaning within UML and OOP.

In UML, composition is a stronger form of aggregation and is sort of like a "owns-a" association.

The GoF design pattern book suggests that in OOP, one should favor composition over inheritance. In this case, composition just means that functionality is provided by referencing a class rather than inheriting from it.

It seems that you have some terms mixed up. Creating and object or calling a factory method is not in itself composition.